# EXTJS setFieldLabel, for fieldcontainer, add style display:block to label and break design

Tags: extjs, styles

I am using this code into a form:

```
{
    xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
    name: 'Label1',
    itemid: 'Label1',
    labelStyle: 'font-weight:bold;padding:0',
    labelWidth: 150,
    margin: '5 0 0 0',
    layout: {
        type: 'hbox',
        align: 'stretchmax'
    },

    style: { display: 'marker !important' }

    fieldDefaults: {
        labelAlign: 'top'
    },

    defaults: { width: 400 },
    fieldLabel: 'Teste de label',

    items: [
        { id: 'txtID', name: 'txtName', fieldLabel: 'Field Label', allowBlank: true, labelWidth: 150, xtype: 'textfield', enforceMaxLength: true, maxLength: 10, flex: 1, margin: '0 0 0 5' }
        , { id: 'txtID2', name: 'txtName2', fieldLabel: 'Field Label2', allowBlank: true, labelWidth: 150, xtype: 'textfield', flex: 1, margin: '0 0 0 5' }
    ]
}
```

This look good on screen, but, i need to change the FieldContainer Label content dynamically.
So i am doing the following:

```
 obj = Ext.getCmp('ID');
 obj.setFieldLabel("New label text");
```

The FieldContainer gets the new Label text but Ext add a style: `display:block` to the table TD tha contains the label. Then the fields cames over the Label.

Is it possible to make Ext do not add this style?
I try to add style: `{ display: 'marker !importat' }` but did not work

Comment: Hello,
I manage to find a solution. Maybe it;s not the best one but works.
Instead using obj.setFieldLabel('new label') i did:

obj.fieldLabel = label;
obj.labelEl.update(label);